# Regex email validation on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do a very basic jQuery validation of an email via a regex on submit. My HTML:

```
<form action="POST" id="form">
<input type="email" id="customer_email" placeholder="email here" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

var emailinput = $('#customer_email').value();

if (email_reg.test(emailinput) == false) {
    window.alert('no good');
}
});
```

To my understanding, for this to work I need to get the value of the input via email input (which I do on line 4) and run a regex on it.

When submit is clicked, the standard input error appears on the form, and not the window alert. Feel free to view a Codepen outlining this here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYmJLW?editors=1010

Comment: I tested your regex using this email: "2039i#@gmail.com" and it worked just fine. It alerted your warning message ("no good"). What email did you try ? Maybe the regex has to be changed for your case.

Comment: I'm using the Regex on my personal site and it works great. The issue was that I was using `type="email"` and I guess it overrides JS validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the actual form submission, and use `.val()` instead of `.value()` on the input.

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var emailinput = $('#customer_email').val();

    if (email_reg.test(emailinput) == false) {
        window.alert('no good');
    }
});
```

By declaring your input as `type="email"` your browser will do the validity checking (you don't need to do it yourself then), if you want to circumvent that use `type="text"`.

Comment: Oh I see. so if you use `type="email"` the browser does the validity check and overrides the JS? I didn't know that. Wouldn't `e.preventDefault();` not allow that to happen?

Comment: @kawnah `e.preventDefault()` just prevents the submission. To be honest I do not know why the Javascript is skipped completely and why it interacts like that, weird browser quirks I guess